# Calling similar functions with different parameter count with a single templated function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have two functions which call external library functions except one has two extra parameters (let’s say the extra parameters are always zero).

```
void func1(int a, int b)
{
    libDoAThing(a, b);
}

void func1Special(int a, int b)
{
    libDoAThingWithTwoExtraParams(a, b, 0, 0);
}
```

Is there any way to combine these methods into a single method which can be called as such:

```
func1<libDoAThing>{10, 10};
func1<libDoAThingWithTwoExtraParams>{10, 10};
```

I'm not sure how to handle the two extra parameters in the function call when templating.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. What is the real problem are you trying to solve. Not, not the one about "combining these methods", but the real problem to which you believe the solution involves having a single template function of this kind.

Comment: This was the solution which was suggested to me by a co-worker. I was asking this question because I did not know how to technically implement it.

Comment: Solution to what, exactly? Rather than assuming that this is the solution, and try to figure out how to do it, it makes more sense to describe the real problem. It's very possible that a completely different approach exists which is much more simpler, and straightforward.

Comment: I don't disagree with you that there may be a better overall solution to this problem. However, I'm interested in how this would be accomplished code-wise since I don't know how to do this. This is more of a "how would I code this?" rather than "what is the best solution to my situation?" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use at least C++11, you can fix the last two parameters with `std::bind()` or, I suggest, with a lambda function.

So you don't need a template parameter: you can pass the resulting lambda as an argument of `func1()` and call it inside.

The following is a full working example with lambda

```
#include <iostream>

void foo (int a, int b)
 { std::cout << "foo: " << a << ", " << b << std::endl; }

void bar (int a, int b, int c, int d)
 { std::cout << "bar: " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " 
      << d << std::endl; }

void func1 (void(*f)(int, int), int x, int y)
 { f(x, y); }

int main ()
 {
   auto l { [](int a, int b){ bar(a, b, 0, 0); } };

   func1(foo, 1, 2);
   func1(l,   3, 4);
 }
```